# using Jsoup how we know whether a tag name exist in HTML page or not

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to get some values from a web site. and want to use a method to check if one rule is available get the value from that rule or else the second one. for example

```
Document d=Jsoup.connect("some site name")
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 3912.101.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36").timeout(100000).get();
```

This is sample i have done but not working

```
if(d.getAllElements().hasAttr("bld lrg red")) { 
    System.out.println("insidee IF"); 
    Elements e = d.select("span[class=bld lrg red]"); 
    String TEXT=e.text(); 
    System.out.println(TEXT);
} else {
    System.out.println("inside ELSE ");
    Elements e=d.select("td[class~=(?i)(toeNewPrice|toeUsedPrice)]");
    String TEXT=e.text();
    System.out.println(TEXT);
}
```

if bld lrg red is available then take from if and if not available take value from else

Comment: `bld lrg red` are these class names or attribute names? Can you share an html snippet?

Comment: it is a span class .. <span class="bld lrg red"> $379.00</span>

Comment: <td class="toeNewPrice">
                      <a href="http://www.aaa.com/gp/offer-listing/1608198065/ref=lp_1_1_3_np_1_main_olp?s=books&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1406096241&amp;sr=1-3&amp;condition=new">$16.74</a></td>
                  <td class="toeUsedPrice">
                      <a href="http://www.aaa.com/gp/offer-listing/1608198065/ref=lp_1_1_3_up_1_main_olp?s=books&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1406096241&amp;sr=1-3&amp;condition=used">$18.93</a></td>

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking for a span tag with all those classes the try like

```
if(doc.select("span.bld.lrg.red").size() > 0) { 
    System.out.println("insidee IF"); 
    Elements e = d.select("span[class=bld lrg red]"); 
    String TEXT=e.text(); 
    System.out.println(TEXT);
} else {
    System.out.println("inside ELSE ");
    Elements e=d.select("td[class~=(?i)(toeNewPrice|toeUsedPrice)]");
    String TEXT=e.text();
    System.out.println(TEXT);
}
```